# Как избежать циклов при создании схемы в MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, циклы

Кроме связи таблицы Авиарейсы с таблицей Туры, мне также нужно связать Отели_ТипРазм с Турами, но происходит образование циклов. Как можно это исправить? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего плохого в не вижу в вопросе. Понятие "цикличность" здесь не применимо. Просто немного избыточная информация по связям в упомянутых таблицах. Смело делайте как описали.

Comment: @MikhailGrebenev при попытке создания связи появляется ошибка:
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Отели_ОтелиТипРазм' on table 'Отели_ТипРазм' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Убирать каскадное обновление и реализовывать это через триггеры?

Comment: Изображение структуры БД не совсем удачное. Обычно структура изображается в древовидном виде, где сверху основной элемент, обрастает внизу дополнительными. Тогда будет видна избыточная зависимость таблиц. Надо найти центральную сущность (например Тур) и от нее рисовать структуру. Пока непонятно из картинки что здесь основное. В сложных структурах также используется связь многие ко многим, которая позволяет избежать описанной "цикличности". В общем, еще подумайте.

Comment: В вашем случае каскадное удаление от городов вообще стоит убрать, и не реализовывать его через триггеры. Если это живой проект (или хотя бы реалистичный) - то пользователь не должен иметь возможности снести из системы авиарейсы, отели и прочее просто удалив город. Т.е. запрет на удаление в таком случае - вполне нормальная практика.